# Python3 - turn a nested list into a readable string or table

Tags: python-3.x

I have wrote a Python3 script to send test emails and record the details. These details are recorded in a nested list.

I now want to convert this nested list into a readable format and attach it onto another email which goes to myself.

I have this which can print it to my local screen:

```
        for item in sentmail:
        print( "|",item[0]," "*(8-len(item[0])),
        "|",item[1]," "*(20-len(item[1])),
        "|",item[2]," "*(30-len(item[2])),
        "|",item[3])
```

which outputs:

```
emails sent during this session
| Time      | Subject              | To                     | From
| 09:20:06  | email - subject      | recipient              | sender
| 09:20:06  | email - subject      | recipient              | sender
| 09:20:06  | email - subject      | recipient              | sender
```

I would like to capture something similar that can be called as a string variable so I can use it in an email like this

```
msg = MIMEText('this is the text that goes in the body of the email' + logs_table + 'added as a variable')
```

log_table is defined at the top of the script with

```
log_table = ""
```

function to populate the variable is currently:

```
def Log_table(sentmail):
    for item in sentmail:
        log_table += "|"+item[0]+" "*(8-len(item[0]))+"|"+item[1]+" "*(20-len(item[1]))+"|"+item[2]+" "*(30-len(item[2]))+"|"+item[3]
```

Function that sends the log email is:

```
def Logs_email(recipient, log_table):
with open('emailTXTFile.txt', 'r') as emailTXTFile:
    EmailMSGTXT = emailTXTFile.read()

#build the email
msg = MIMEText('this is the email content' + log_table)
msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', recipient))
msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('sender', 'sender'))
msg['Subject'] = 'logs for ' + client
msg['Date'] = email.header.Header( email.utils.formatdate() )
msg['Message-ID'] = email.header.Header( email.utils.make_msgid() )

#log the sent email
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
mail_info = [timestamp, 'session logs', recipient, test_address ]
sentmail.append(mail_info)
server.sendmail(test_address, recipient, msg.as_string())
```

Any pointers and advice is appreciated, thank you in advance

(I have tried different variations of what I have and understand but encounter syntax errors with the loop or the variable doesn't hold the value. I have also tried the code as a function or in line with the main code.)

Comment: current error is: `emails sent during this session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 197, in <module>
    Log_table(sentmail)
  File "./script.py", line 56, in Log_table
    log_table += "|"+item[0]+" "*(8-len(item[0]))+"|"+item[1]+" "*(20-len(item[1]))+"|"+item[2]+" "*(30-len(item[2]))+"|"+item[3]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'log_table' referenced before assignment`

Comment: #Solved: moved Jammy Dodger's solution into each function that was formatting logs and it worked. I was originally missing the + signs when trying to create the variable.  resetting the variable locally instead of updating it globally solved the missing values issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table to a variable

```py
message = ""
for item in sentmail:
    message += "|"+item[0]+" "*(8-len(item[0]))+
    "|"+item[1]+" "*(20-len(item[1]))+
    "|"+item[2]+" "*(30-len(item[2]))+
    "|"+item[3])

msg = MIMEText('this is the text that goes in the body of the email' + message + 'added as a variable')
```

Comment: having issue getting message to keep the value. it runs but doesnt keep the value. Will show how I am typing it out

Comment: What do you mean by `keep the value`? Once the script ends, the value will be lost

Comment: I've added in some more code for more context. At first I was missing the +s and just replaced print with the variable. At the end I had a print(log_table) to see what the string looked like but it wouldn't print anything so I'm assuming the string is empty